# Accessing data appended to an ELF binary

Tags: linux, gcc, build, elf

I have a static ELF binary which reads data from a zipfile. In order to simplify distribution, I want to append the zipfile to the binary, like so:

```
$ cat mydata.zip >> mybinary
```

I know that doing so won't damage mybinary, but I don't know how to access the contents of mydata.zip having done so.  Is it possible?  If so, how?

In the past, I've used the trick of appending the data then appending the length of the data, so that all I have to do is open the binary, read the last int of the stream, rewind that length then start unzipping, but that won't work here for various reasons (for instance, I can't guarantee that the file will still be on disc when the zipfile comes to be needed).

Super-extra-doubleplus-points all round if the solution works across OS X and MinGW.

Comment: The reason the .exe won't be on disk is because it's being run-time extracted from a packer/protector?

Comment: Potentially, yes. I'm not in control at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the assumption at the start of the execution of the application you have access to the file, then opening a handle to it should prevent the operating system from obliterating the file on-disk until the last reference to the file has been closed. This would allow you to seek through the file to you heart's content, using that file handle without worry.

Create a global variable:

```
int app_fd;
```

The process for most of these is the same, in the main routine, simply issue:

```
app_fd = open(argv[0], O_RDONLY);
```

at the start of execution. When it comes to the point in the execution that you need to access the zip file, then simply use the file descriptor, rather than the filename.

At run-time, if you don't have some form of handle to the original contents of the application, then you will probably not be able to access the content of the zip file. This is due to the loader only mapping in the sections of the file that are expected. The content at the end of the binary would be considered garbage and not mapped in.

To accomplish the mapping of the zip file into memory, you would need to follow a different tack. You would need to embed the .zip into an ELF(linux)/COFF(Windows)/Mach-O(Mac OS X) section of the binary that has properties set such that it is guaranteed to be mapped into the application (this requires a lot of pre-work in the app, and a lot more post-work in the processing). It's not trivial, and probably involves quite a bit of coding to get it right for each of the platforms.

As an aside, it is not trivial to delete an application from a windows system while that application is running (I think you can move it if it resides on NTFS though).

Comment: The open(argv[0]) trick is where I started, so that's my default, if you like.  Mapping the zip file into memory is *relatively* straightforward once you've figured out the objcopy settings, but it's more invasive to the application source than is ideal, which is why I'm looking for a third way...

Comment: As mentioned in my second last paragraph, it's going to be invasive and platform dependent once you don't have access to the underlying file either by file descriptor or name. Written once, though, a routine to access the section from the file can be reused as a library call...

Comment: You can actually open /proc/self/exe which will yield the very binary that's loaded into memory, even if it has been deleted since starting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you concatenate an ELF file and a zip file, the resulting file is **both** (AFAIU) a valid ELF file and a valid zip file.

Demo:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello
$ (cat hello ; test.zip) > hello2
$ chmod u+x hello2
$ ./hello2
Hello
$ unzip ./hello2
Archive:  ./hello2
warning [./hello2]:  6704 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
   119458  1999-11-24 13:08   hello.txt
```

Many libraries (zlib, zzip) (erronously?) do not recognize such a file as a valid zip file but libminizip can do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <minizip/unzip.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unzFile uf = unzOpen(argv[0]);
  unzGoToFirstFile(uf);
  char filename_inzip[256] = {0};
  unz_file_info64 file_info = {0};
  const char *string_method = NULL; 
  unzGetCurrentFileInfo64(uf, &file_info, filename_inzip, sizeof(filename_inzip), NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
  printf("%s\n", filename_inzip);    
  return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
$ ./unzipme2
foo.txt
```